How to filter with not-contain condition in TanStack Table?
enter image description here
enter image description here
Currently, the filter condition based on contains still works very well, but my wish is to filter values ​​according to the not-contains condition! Thank you everyone for your help.

In the column definitions, you can set up a custom filter function.
This is a short snippet for you to reference.
{
 accessorKey: "funds",
 header: ({ column }) => {},
 cell: ({ row }) => {},
 filterFn: (rows, columnIds, filterValue) => {
  if ((filterValue as string).includes("!")) {
    return !rows
      .getValue<string>(columnIds)
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(filterValue.slice(1));
  }
  return rows
    .getValue<string>(columnIds)
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(filterValue);
 },
},

As for the search input:
<Input
  placeholder="Filter by fund..."
        value={(table.getColumn("funds")?.getFilterValue() as string) ?? ""}
        onChange={(event) => {
          table.getColumn("funds")?.setFilterValue(event.target.value);
        }}
        className="max-w-sm"
/>

For my implementation, if user were to type '!' as the first character in the string, it will return the rows that give the opposite results.
Hope it helps!
